# Escaping A String Within an Escaped String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am writing a generator.

I want to the generator to create 'model' names. Such as

```
rails g my_custom_generator foo
```

or

```
rails g my_custom_generator bar
```

Based on rails, I can create a model for the chosen name using #{class_name}.

The {class_name} will become foo or bar depending on your choice.

Still with me? Great.  My question is as follows:

I want to generate an edit form, and I want to fill in the model name in an already escaped string. Something like:

```
f.input :name, value="#{@model.name}"
```

My code above already looks like that.  I want to now translate that for the generator like

```
f.input :name, value=#"{@#{class_name}.name}"
```

But that doesn't work.  Does anyone know how to escape an already escape string...?  What's the approach to take here.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can avoid escaping by using single quotes:

```
"#{@model.name}"
# => "Test"
'#{@model.name}'
# => "\#{@model.name}"
```

So if you're intending to defer evaluation for one round, you should just escape like that or make it a more literal version:

```
"\#{@#{class_name}.name}"
```

That can be evaluated twice, though I'm not sure that it'll work exactly as planned in the generator system. You'd have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Various sources ([this](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/blob/master/lib/generators/nifty/scaffold/templates/views/haml/_form.html.haml) and [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html)) indicate that files to be generated from are processed by ERB, so using Ruby's string interpolation in these files outside of `<%=` and `%>` is useless.

Splice it like so:

```
f.input :name, value=#"{@<%= class_name %>.name}"
```